# How not to display ssml tags on Alexa screen device while sending notification in Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, proactive, alexa-notification

1. I have implemented Alexa Proactive events to send Notification
   through Our skill in Alexa. It's working fine. But Problem is we
   have added SSML tag say to speak as digits  2212545  like this to handle Audio. Rightnow this  tag is displaying on screen of Alexa device. We don't want to display SSML tag. Please can anyone tell how can we remove these SSML tag in our Alexa notification while displaying
   This is body i am sending

   {"timestamp":"2021-02-23T07:06:00.693Z","referenceId":"db8b343f-5639-431c-a436-e7c6eee604c4","expiryTime":"2021-02-24T07:06:00.693Z","event":{"name":"AMAZON.MessageAlert.Activated","payload":{"state":{"status":"UNREAD"},"messageGroup":{"creator":{"name": "Amount 5000 for user id 2212545 will be credited on
   2021/10/02"},"count":1}}},"relevantAudience":{"type":"Unicast","payload":{"user":
   USER_ID}}}

Answer (score 0):

I have a small library for formatting and such and just run my display text through a small regular expression.

I found this here and have used it ever since.

https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/5433/strip-ssml-tags-for-card-output.html

```
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
cardContent = someTextWithSSMLTags.replace(regex, "");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I am using Alexa Proactive event for sending Notification. This will not work in my case. Because Alexa Notification (Proactive events) has fixed schema. Please have a look at above body

Comment: Ah I didn't understand the Alexa Proactive Event part and pardon me if I am still missing something, but where is the SSML?

Comment: { "timestamp": "timestamp", "referenceId": "db8b34",
    "expiryTime": "expiryedate",
    "event": {
        "name": "AMAZON.MessageAlert.Activated",
        "payload": {
            "state": {
                "status": "UNREAD"
            },
            "messageGroup": {
                "creator": {
                    "name": "Order Id <say-as interprets-as ='digits'>251624 </say-as>"
                },
                "count": 1
            }
        }}, "relevantAudience": { "type": "Unicast", "payload": { "user": USER_ID
        }
    }
}

Comment: I have added the request body for Proactive event and according to my use case I have added Order Id in name parameter when I say Alexa what are my new notifications Alexa speaks correctly but same notification displayed  with tag like this <say-as interprets-as ='digits'>251624 </say-as> . I don't want that tag to be displayed on screen